# ListView scroll in marshmallow getting slow with images

Tags: android, listview, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a `ListView` with a `ImageView` covering the row. (I'm loading the image with Picasso. I had tried glide first but Picasso is slightly faster) It works smoothly enough on lollipop and kitkat, but on marshmallow the scroll is getting extremely slow and sometimes it is getting ANR messages.

**Here's my xml for the list item:**

```
<RelativeLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:clipChildren="false"
       android:clipToPadding="false">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="170dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/img_genre_bg"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <!--android:background="@color/trans_black"-->

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/img_play"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/play_button"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/tv_genre_name"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/img_play"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/tv_genre_id"
                        android:visibility="gone"/>
                </RelativeLayout>


                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="3dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

**Listview:**

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lv_genre"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:persistentDrawingCache="scrolling"
    android:scrollingCache="false">
</ListView>
```

**getView():**

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    View rowview=view;
    if(rowview==null){
        rowview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_genre_list,viewGroup,false);
    }
    id = (TextView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.tv_genre_id);
    TextView name = (TextView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.tv_genre_name);
    ImageView img_genre_bg = (ImageView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.img_genre_bg);
    ImageView img_play = (ImageView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.img_play);


    opensans = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font/OpenSans-Light.ttf");
    name.setTypeface(opensans);

    GENRE genre=new GENRE();
    genre=genres.get(position);
    id.setText(genre.getGenre_id());
    name.setText(genre.getGenre_name());


        Picasso
            .with(context)
            .load(genre.getGenre_image())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
            .into(img_genre_bg);

    return rowview;
}
```

I had tried loading the image on separate `AsyncTask` thread but still it got stuck on scrolling. Changing it to `RecyclerView` also didn't helped.

Comment: you are not using `ViewHolder` pattern and creating typeface while every row is created

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are creating your `Typeface` everytime a row is created. The overhead of creating an `Asset` everytime a row is created probably slows the execution.

Move this piece of code to the `Constructor` of your class;

```
opensans = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font/OpenSans-Light.ttf");
```

Then you can use that already created type as:

```
name.setTypeface(opensans);
```

It is better to move to `RecyclerView` which is more suitable since it manages memory more efficiently than `ListView`.

Comment: Ok, I did it but It didn't change much on the speed issue.

Comment: Also you have to use a `ViewHolder` pattern. You are creating new views with each row. This example demonstrates how to use `ViewHolder` :  https://dzone.com/articles/optimizing-your-listview